# trying to echo xml data to html table with php

Tags: php, html, xml

So I have almost the output that I want except for one thing. I can not seem to figure out how to print a specific part of my XML file on new lines inside of an HTML table using PHP to echo it out.

I am not the greatest when it comes to PHP, but I find it fun to dabble with. As for my code that I have so far, I will post my PHP section.

```
<?php
$file="badscifimovies.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("no load");
echo <<<EOF
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Producers/Director</th>
    <th>Stars</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>MST3000</th>
  </tr>
EOF;
foreach($xml->movie as $movie){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->title}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->year}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->director->producer}</td>";
  foreach($movie->stars->star as $stars){
    echo "<td>{$stars[0]}</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>{$movie->budget}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->mst}</td>";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The output that I am looking for is with the "Stars" section.
the part of the XML that I am getting at is this:

```
<stars>
  <star>Name One</star>
  <star>Name two</star>
  <star>Name three</star>
</star>
```

I can not seem to print each one of those on a separate line. All of my other code print out the rest of the XML document fine (probable because there is 1 element per movie). For the stars section it prints all three stars out side by side, but will print each of my movie sections out on a new line like it should.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info from me I will post more up.

Comment: Could you paste wider part of used XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($xml->movie as $movie){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->title}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->year}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->director->producer}</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  foreach($movie->stars->star as $stars){
    echo $stars[0] . '<br/>';
  }
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->budget}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$movie->mst}</td>";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

I think this should work. You were creating a new `<td>` element for every star, but you only had one `<th>` tag corresponding.

Comment: Ha thats great! Thank you. Just like all programming, there has to be sort of really easy fix that is over looked until you have some one look it over. Thank you again. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

XML file (employee.xml)

```
<root>
<person>
    <sno>1</sno>
    <name>person1</name>
    <phno>098687667</phno>
</person>
<person>
    <sno>2</sno>
    <name>person2</name>
    <phno>897876756</phno>
</person>
<person>
    <sno>3</sno>
    <name>person3</name>
    <phno>986875675</phno>
</person>
```

PHP code

```
<body>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("employee.xml")
or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$element_name = array();                                    //get all xml element name
foreach ($xml->children()->children() as $value) {
$element_name[] = $value->getName();
}
?>
<table border = "1">
<thead>
<tr>
<?php
foreach ($element_name as $value) {             //display table head
echo "<th>{$value}</th>";
}
?>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($xml->children() as $value) {              //display table data
echo "<tr>";    
for ($i = 0; $i < count($element_name); $i++) {
echo "<td>{$value->children()->$element_name[$i]}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamic convertion:

http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-xml-to-html-table-elment-convertion.html

for any xml...